# Right way to test connection strings

Tags: c#, sql

I tried this code on an array of 3 connection strings without any complaints.My question is, is it okay to invoke multiple dispose calls on the same object?

```
foreach (var s in strings)
{
      connection.ConnectionString = s;
      connection.Open();
      connection.Close();
      connection.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: If you dispose the connection it is just by chance that this code works on the second loop

Comment: Disposed objects should not be available to use again.

Comment: @Steve what is an ideal pattern to implement connection testing code?

Comment: Create a connection inside the loop inside a `using` statement.  You gain nothing by re-using the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
bool TestConnection<T>(string connectionString) where T : IDbConnection, new
{
    using(T con = new T())
    {
        con.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        connection.Open();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Another way to implement connection testing code is with an extension method (note this does not dispose the connection object):

```
public static Tuple<bool, Exception> TestConnection(this IDbConnection connection)
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        connection.Close();
        return new Tuple<bool, Exception>(true, null);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return new Tuple<bool, Exception>(false, e);
    }
}
```

Please note in this version I'm returning a Tuple of bool and Exception so whoever use this code can get the information on why the connection failed, but not have to wrap the call in a try...catch block. Of course, you can choose to simply return a bool just like in the first example, this is just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: You can drop the `.Close()` on the `using` version.

Answer (score 0):

You should fix your code this way:

```
foreach (var s in strings)
{
      connection.ConnectionString = s;
      connection.Open();
      connection.Close();
}
```

Connection doesn't need to dispose, or atleast you shoudln't dispose an object that you want to use again.

Anyway this isn't a  good approach.

You should have a

```
using(DbContext db = new DbContext()){
   //SQL Actions
}
```

for every db relative code, to avoid problems ^^

Comment: This piece of code is just a diagnostic util that is going to sit outside the context of our main application (that uses EF with Sql Server)

Comment: Any existing effective pattern would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool TestConnection(IDbConnection con)
        {
            using (con)
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    con.Close();
                    return true;
                }
                catch
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's "ok" with what you are doing (completely different connect everytime with no ran queries) but as Amy said in the comments, it really doesn't get you anything special. Should probably abide by the wisdom of not reusing disposed objects.

Also for SqlConnection, calling Close then dispose is repetitive since it will call its close upon dispose.

Going to throw my code into the mix as well, comments in code:

```
    private bool DBValidCheck(string connection)
    {
        //Using statement releases the object that implement iDisposable once it exits the block. Takes care of the dispose
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connection))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Travis-The idea is there are several components that should respond to health check ping.I wanted to have utility that will just take a connection string and try connect to the DB thats being pointed at. 1 component could have just one conn string while another may have 5. the for loop is just a recreation of what could happen. I have a DBChecker class that will have 1 IDbConnection instance injected. Callers could use a single instance of the checker and call the method to test the strings they have. So I want my connection object to live in a valid state for as many strings it has to test.

Comment: If that is th case (and I understand what you are saying) then read up on connection pooling here, it may not even be worth disposing unless you fear that you will hit thdo max pool size: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling